# ExtJS Window close resets grid scrollbar

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, window, scrollbar

I ran into this weird issue. I open a window through action column of a grid and when I close the window I see the scrollbar of grid shifts to top.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/q9e

**Please scroll the grid to the bottom first**

ExtJS version 5.1.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser are you using? And have you tried it in a different browser?

Comment: It is with all the browsers. The important thing i forgot to mention was that you need to scroll the grid to the bottom.

Comment: Perhaps what you are seeing is it scrolling to the selected row within the grid. Selecting the lock icon does not cause a row selection. As an example, select a middle row. Then scroll way up or down and select any lock icon. Close the popup window and you will get  scrolled to the middle where your row selection is still located.